# Regex to match url with and without slash

Tags: regex, url, mod-rewrite

We have this regex in our .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html
```

It matchs urls like: `https://example.com/lib`
to a file called `lib.html`

We need it to also match: `https://example.com/lib/`
to the same file

Thanks.

Tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)?/$ $1.html
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/]*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Like `^([^\./]+)/?$` https://regex101.com/r/ESakrS/1

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.html [L]`

Comment: @anubhava Please post your solution.

Comment: None of this works. This is litespeed I should probably add if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it as two separate rules to keep it simple:

```
RewriteRule (?!.*\.html$)^(.+)\/$ $1.html [last]
RewriteRule (?!.*\.html$)^(.+)$ $1.html [last]
```

It'll first try to match an on a URL ending with `/` and if that fails it'll continue to the next rule. The negative lookahead, `(?!.*\.html$)`, is there to not rewrite URLs already ending with `.html`.

The `[last]` flag makes it stop processing more rules in case there's a match.

If you prefer to combine both in one rule:

```
RewriteRule (?!.*\.html$)^(.+?)\/?$ $1.html [last]
```

Answer (score -1):

hello try this regex `(\w+)\/?$`

Comment: Hi, thanks. But no good. Also everytime I try /? after the () the non / url doesn't match also.